# Validity about subspace set equality proof

Tags: linear-algebra

prove that if W2 is a subspace of V such that U ⊂ W2, then W2 equals to either U or K

Proof:

Assume that W2 is a subspace of V and U ⊂ W2, want to show W2 equals to either U or V.

$If\ W_2 = U,\ we\ are\ done\\If\ W_2 \neq U, show\ W_2=V\\ W_2\subset V:\\W_2\subset V\ by\ the\ statement\ W_2\ is\ a\ subspace\ of\ V\ we\ are\ done.\\V \subset W_2:\\If\ W_2\neq U, There\ exist\ y\in W_2\ and\ y \notin U\ by\ statement\ U\subset W_2\\But\ W_2\ is\ a\ subspace\ of\ V,\ so\ y\in W_2\implies y\in V $
So $y=u_1 + ck$ because $V=U+span\{k\}$, where $u_1 \in U\ and\ c\in \mathbb{R}$
Since $U\subset W_2, u_1 \in W_2$

Case 1: c=0
Let $x \in V$, $x=u_1 + 0k \implies x=u_1 \in W_2$, so $x \in W_2$, we have $x \in V \implies x \in W_2 $, so $V\subset W_2$

Case 2: $c \neq 0$
(eq1) $ck = y-u_1 \in W_2$ since $u_1 \in W_2$ by above and $y\in W_2$ by assumption
$\frac{1}{c}*(ck) \implies k \in W_2$ Since scalar multiplication is closed in W2
Let $x \in V$, $x=u_1 + ck \implies x=u_1 \in W_2\ and\ k\in\ W_2$, so $x \in W_2$, we have $x \in V \implies x \in W_2 $, so $V\subset W_2$

$V\subset W_2$ and $W_2\subset V$ is showed, $W_2 = V$, and therefore, if W2 does not equal to U, it must equal to V

Am I doing the proof correctly? If I did some parts wrong or missed explainations, please point out. Any input is helpful!

Comment: OK. But case 1: $c=0$ does not occur if $y=u_1+ck\in W_2$ \ $U,$ otherwise $y=u_1\in U. $